# issue to query huge dataset using Yii ADO

Tags: php, yii

I have a table with over hundred of thousand of rows. When I use below:

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM thistable')->query();
```

The query failed, however testing much small tables, it was fine. I wanted to backup my current database, and I followed this link:

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/29291-full-database-backup/

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use mysqldump  (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html)?

Comment: What do you mean by "failed"? Any error message?

Comment: Hi Valery, some web site hosting company may not allow us to us mysqldump function for security issue.

Comment: To answer Michael's question, I mean backup failed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to avoid such queries in big tables. It can cause mysql crash or server dump. And thats not yii problem.
Advices:

1.Use indexes (but carefully sometimes they slowing down queries - COUNT for example).

2.Always make limits in your queries :  `SELECT * FROM thistable LIMIT 50`.

3.If you using InnoDB for total count use `EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM thistable`. In myISAM `COUNT()` works fast.

4.Avoid all joins. Even join on small table(<100 records) can cause 30-100% slow on queries.

I assume that 2nd point is your problem. 
For example:

`SELECT * FROM thistable LIMIT 30` => result (32,415,735 all, Query took 0.0184 sec.)`

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM thistable'=> result (31,912,535 all, Query took 215.14 sec.)`

Comment: thank you! I am using innoDB. However how can I backup database using LIMIT? I won't use join since I am only querring every table.

Comment: If you want to backup you need to use something else. There are alot of ways -cron+dump(efficient for highloads),rsync, replication to slave and so on. Plently of ways explained already, but its not php work to do backups on highloads.

Comment: Thanks. the project I am working on is using php Yii framework. BTW, what is cron+dump?

Comment: Cron is linux job manager. With it you can do automatic dumps (for example i use cron+rsync every 30 minutes). Dump means `mysqldump`. Here is a link how to make it http://wiki.lunarpages.com/Backup_Databases_using_a_cron. But i dont recommed this way on big databases (for example i have 120g database) because this will be very efficient.